# Enforce both correct API Key and JWT User Token in REST API with Spring Boot Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm currently working on an REST API in Spring Boot.

Multiple People shall build clients for this API, so I want to distinguish them by API Keys.

Also users are able to login to the service via an authorization process to get a JWT (I know that's not very RESTful, but that's the best way I can think of doing it).

I implemented three filter classes for these purposes:

- `APIKeyAuthFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter`
- `JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`
- `JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter`

and everything works quite nice individually.

The problem is, that the security layer treats both Auth Types equally. So e.g. I can get stuff only users should see via only an API Key and there is no need for an API-Key once I have a JWT.

I guess the problem lies in this code in my subclass of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`:

```
httpSecurity
    .antMatcher("/**")
    .csrf().disable()
    .sessionManagement()
    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
    .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
    .addFilter(apiKeyFilter)
    .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Or is my whole approach wrong and I need to add API Keys in a whole different way?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security has the notion of "granted authorities", or in other words, authorities that the system grants to an `Authentication`.

Granted authorities are Spring Security's way of distinguishing what each user is allowed to do. Generally, these are granted in [a `UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-userdetailsservice) or, in the case of JWTs and Spring Security 5.1+, [a `JwtAuthenticationConverter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/config/src/test/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/oauth2/server/resource/OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurerTests.java#L1461).

You asked also: "Or is my whole approach wrong and I need to add API Keys in a whole different way?" - this question is a little broad, but you might consider as a first step having both authentication mechanisms result in a JWT. A better step would probably be to separate that concern out to an Authorization Server (which does a great job at issuing JWTs) so that your service can just focus on validating JWTs only.

Comment: So your idea is to put the API Key as an additional parameter to the `/login` path and then contain it within the JWT?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand enough detail about your situation to advise, but I can say that it's very typical for API clients to use Basic authentication and end users to use Form-based authentication. I don't really see the motive for combining the two as I think you are suggesting. I think it would be odd for a rest client to hit a `/login` endpoint. As for JWTs, yes some kind of client id probably makes sense since you have a requirement for tracking clients and their API usage. Fair warning, though, you may be on the road to rebuilding OAuth. I'd be happy to have a chat, if that helps.

Comment: Let's try this: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/195225/regarding-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-56639323